# mysql2 gem install error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, mysql2

im trying to install mysql2 gem after it failed to install on a bundle install. 
when i run

> $ sudo gem install mysql2 --
>   --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

i get the following error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing mysql2:    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>     /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
> ```
>
> checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes checking for
>   rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes checking for mysql.h... yes checking
>   for errmsg.h... yes checking for mysqld_error.h... yes creating
>   Makefile
>
> make compiling client.c In file included from client.c:1: In file
>   included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8: In file included from
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:105:37:
>   error: 'ruby_check_sizeof_long' declared as an array with a negative
>   size typedef char ruby_check_sizeof_long[SIZEOF_LONG == sizeof(long) ?
>   1 : -1];
>                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from client.c:1:
>   In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8: In file included from
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:24:
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/ruby/config.h:24:21: note: instantiated from:
>
> ## define SIZEOF_LONG 8
>
> ```
>                 ^ In file included from client.c:1: In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8: In file included from
> ```
>
> /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:109:38:
>   error: 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' declared as an array with a negative
>   size typedef char ruby_check_sizeof_voidp[SIZEOF_VOIDP ==
>   sizeof(void*) ? 1 : -1];
>                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from
>   client.c:1: In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8: In file included
>   from
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:24:
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/ruby/config.h:28:22: note: instantiated from:
>
> ## define SIZEOF_VOIDP 8
>
> ```
>                  ^ In file included from client.c:1: In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8: In file included from
> ```
>
> /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1382:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:34:
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/st.h:67:45:
>   error: 'st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t' declared as an array with a
>   negative size typedef char st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t[SIZEOF_VOIDP
>   == (int)sizeof(st_index_t) ? 1 : -1];
>                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from
>   client.c:1: In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8: In file included
>   from
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:24:
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/ruby/config.h:28:22: note: instantiated from:
>
> ## define SIZEOF_VOIDP 8
>
> ```
>                  ^ 3 errors generated. make: *** [client.o] Error 1
> ```
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out

$ which ruby

> /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby

$ where mysql

> /usr/local/bin/mysql

what am i missing?

Comment: which mysql version do you have installed?

Comment: I see many same posts from google http://goo.gl/gm9q5

Answer (score 1):

If you’re planning on using the mysql2 gem for your application then you’ll want to install the `libmysqlclient-dev` package before you do that. For more detail: 
http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it'll help

cd /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7

> gem install mysql -- 
>   --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

and if this doesn't work then install 
 **libmysqlclient15-dev**

Whenever you can't build "native extensions", it means there is some lib 
or lib-dev missing. Generally you'll need to do a

```
sudo apt-get install 
lib-???-dev
```

or 
`sudo apt-get install build_essential`.

```
'sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev'
```

Comment: apt-get is exclusively for Ubontu right? im running osx 10.7. how do i install libmysqlclient15-dev on a mac? i have xcode installed.